# Why the return of this Haskell function is different from the return of the function defined?

Tags: haskell

I'm reading this simple [servant tutorial](https://docs.servant.dev/en/stable/tutorial/ApiType.html) to learn haskell. Here's the code:

```
type UserAPI1 = "users" :> Get '[JSON] [User]

data User = User
  { name :: String
  , age :: Int
  , email :: String
  , registration_date :: Day
  } deriving (Eq, Show, Generic)

instance ToJSON User

users1 :: [User]
users1 =
  [ User "Isaac Newton"    372 "isaac@newton.co.uk" (fromGregorian 1683  3 1)
  , User "Albert Einstein" 136 "ae@mc2.org"         (fromGregorian 1905 12 1)
  ]

server1 :: Server UserAPI1
server1 = return users1
```

If `server1 :: Server UserAPI1`, then `return users1` should be a function that when applied, returned the type `Server UserAPI1`. But it's actually a function that returns `[User]`. I'm confused. Why the function return type is different from the return type of the function defined?

Comment: `return` doesn't do what the return statement in C does, it's a *function* that wraps its argument in a *monad*. So the type of `return users1` is not the same as the type of `users1`, it's actually `m [User]` where `m` is some monad. Which monad? I don't know exactly because `Server` is a type family.

Comment: Servant is a fantastic library, but I would absolutely not recommend it for learning the Haskell language from scratch. It uses a lot of non-standard language extensions to do a lot of "magic" at the type level. Type level programming is fascinating and I think becoming more common, but won't make much sense if you're not yet familiar with more "ordinary" Haskell programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If server1 :: Server UserAPI1, then return users1 should be a function that when applied, returned the type Server UserAPI1.

`UserAPI1` is a complex type. We could see it as a data structure—existing at the type level—that describes our API. But to actually serve requests, we need [`Handler`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-server-0.18/docs/Servant-Server-Internal-Handler.html#t:Handler)s, which know how to perform effects, [how to notify errors relevant to the framework](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-server-0.18/docs/Servant-Server-Internal-ServerError.html#t:ServerError), and so on.

The structure of the handlers is clearly determined by the description of the API, but they aren't exactly the same type. Here `Server` enters the scene.

`Server` is something called a ["type family"](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=typefamilies#extension-TypeFamilies). It transforms types into other types. You can think of it as a function that works on types, not on terms. `Server` transforms the description of our API into the actual types of the handlers, which will vary depending on how many paths there are, if they capture parts of the URL as parameters, etc.

In ghci, there's a very useful command to "run" type family applications and inspect their result types. It's called [`:kind!`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html?highlight=kind#ghci-cmd-:kind):

```
:kind! Server UserAPI1
Handler [User]
```

So, when we build the `server1` value, we are really building something of type `Handler [User]`. Looking at the documentation of [`Handler`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-server-0.18/docs/Servant-Server-Internal-Handler.html#t:Handler), we see that it has a [`Monad`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:Monad) instance. That's the reason why [`return`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:return) works here. We are building a trivial handler that returns an already known list of `User`s. Note that `return` in Haskell doesn't have the "early exit" behaviour that it has in other languages. Instead, it's used to inject pure values into monadic contexts.

If `UserAPI1` actually [captured](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-0.18/docs/Servant-API.html#t:Capture) some value from the url path, the type returned by `Server` would change accordingly.

```
type UserAPI2 = "users" :> Capture "foo" Int :> Get '[JSON] [User]
```

It would become a function which takes the value and returns a `Handler`:

```
:kind! Server UserAPI2
Int -> Handler [User]
```